# How can I get the browser to prompt for duplicate file downloads?

Tags: 20.04, downloads, www

Is there any way to get a prompt before downloading a duplicate file in a browser? I sometimes don't remember what I've got and get 2 or more copies of the same file. It would be nice to have a prompt like in Windows.

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Firefox

Open Firefox settings, and search for `save`, and choose "Always ask you where to save files".

Now, if you try to save another file with the same name, the browser asks you if you want to replace the existing (duplicate) file.

Then you can save with a different name, or `Cancel` the download.

### Chromium

Chromium asks you where to save, and tells you if there is a duplicate.

[image]

Comment: Actually, if you click the Download icon in Firefox it will give you the same prompt ('Open With' or 'Save File') regardless of how many times you've downloaded the same (pdf) file. If you select Save File it will save the file again with an incremental number appended to the filename.

Comment: @user68186 I have edited my answer.